# \\*[...] with plus/minus stretch

Tags: positioning, longtable, glue

`\\*[...]` seems not to allow for plus/minus stretch: in a `longtable` where `\\*[3ex]` works, `\\*[3ex plus 2ex minus 1ex]` causes the error

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifdim.
<to be read again> 
                   p
```

(1) Why the error?

(2) Is this a generic problem, or special to `longtable`?

(3) How to work around?

(4) Anything special if `\\*[...]` is followed by `\noalign{\penalty-200}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work in a `tabular` environment (no need for `longtable`). It seems like in a `tabular` environment the optional argument is evaluated using a `\ifdim` construct. Try the following to see that:

```
\ifdim 1ex plus 1pt > 1ex
  yeah
\fi
```

A workaround could be the following:

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{ll}
  foo\\\noalign{\vspace*{2ex plus 1pt minus 2pt}}
bar
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But this will break vertical rules. Also, as mentioned in the comments, this will not result in any glue in most cases as tables are normally boxed, it just solves the error message. An exception to this is the `tabularht` package.

Comment: As I have no vertical rules, this workaround will probably suffice. Putting the `vspace` inside the `noalign` is the clue I was missing, many thanks! Does it matter whether the `penalty` goes before or after the `vspace`?

Comment: Does this really result in a stretchable/shinkable space? I've tested with `\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{ll}
  foo\\\noalign{\vspace*{2ex plus 5cm minus 2pt}}
bar
\end{tabular}\par
\blindtext[3]\par
\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
\end{document}` and the only stretched space is that of `\par`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke A `tabular` is boxed, so stretch and shrink are irrelevant. The case is different for a `longtable`.

Comment: @egreg `\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
  foo\\
  \noalign{\vspace*{2ex plus 5cm minus 2pt}}
bar
\end{longtable}
\blindtext[3]\par
\rule{.5\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
\end{document}` does also not result in a stretched space.

Comment: @Schweinebacke It *would* be different for longtables if it didn't rebox the chunks.

Comment: if there is fill stretch on the page (which there usually is with longtable) finite stretch won't strtech

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the shown answer does not result in a vertical stretch (or shrink), neither with `tabular` (as shown) nor with `longtable`. It only answers how to work around the error message. Correct?

Comment: @Schweinebacke it does seem so.

Comment: Package `tabuarlt` provides tables that must fit a given height and allows vertical glues inside the table.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek didn't know that a package with this functionality exists (though I think you misspelled it).

Comment: @Skillmon Yes, the name is `tabularht`.